# Ndb Model validation with interdependent properties?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to validate an NDB Model. My model is something like :

```
class Sample(ndb.Model):
  x = ndb.IntegerField()
  y = ndb.IntegerField()
```

I want to ensure that x < y at any point of time.

Approaches I have tried :

1. Write Validator function and call it from overridden constructor. But the field values may be changed later. And it should validate everytime it saves
2. Add a _pre_put_hook - but that seems to be overkill. Plus - this won't throw error until an entity is actually saved in datastore

Ideally what I want is that whenever a or b is changed - A function should be triggered which will validate if the entity is valid else throw error.

Note : Currently I am using _pre_put_hook.

Comment: _pre_put_hook isn't overkill.  I think its more appropriate than the validator. If you chnage your validation criteria and an existing entity no longer vaildates you won't be able to retrieve it as the the validation will fail.

Comment: In addition assuring x < y, I would suggest you use a method/setter to set x &  y and validate the relationship then.  And what happens when you create the first instance of Sample what are the default values for x & y.  What if they are not initialised, you validation will fail.  You should manage the relationship between the properties at a higher level and use appropriate methods to express the api.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done outside of the ndb.Model logic.

Just create a function inside the model like the following:

```
class Sample(ndb.Model):
   x = ndb.IntegerField()
   y = ndb.IntegerField()

   @classmethod
   def new(cls, x, y):
     if x >= y:
        raise Exception
     return cls(x=x, y=y)
```

Then replace the generic Exception I have used with a custom one and catch it with a try block.

Comment: This solution doesn't prevent changing `x` or `y` to an invalid value after creation.

Comment: Men it's the same logic. Define a new function called update... that uses the exact same validation.. maybe in a helper method to DRY.